# Monero wallet not working with Ledger on Mac High Sierra (was working previously)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

I've run into a really frustrating issue with my Ledger Nano S and the Monero wallet, and can't seem to get it to work again. The wallet was working previously and now no longer detects my Ledger anymore. I have already run through all the incredibly tedious steps of creating the wallet:

- Booting into recovery mode
- Disabling SIP
- Rebooting
- Adding the necessary smart card ID keys to the Info.plist file
- Booting into recovery mode
- Renabling SIP
- Restart

This allowed me to create the wallet using the GUI and I synced it and sent funds to my wallet and I could see them in the wallet and the wallet was working well.

About a week later I tried to access the wallet again and I am now getting the same error I was getting before I installed the wallet:

> Couldn't open wallet: Fail SCard API : (-2146435069) Invalid handle. Device=0, hCard=0, hContext=1

I've done the following to try rectify this but to no avail:

- Checked the USB cable and verified it's working and is the same one I used when creating the wallet and received the funds.
- I've opened the Info.plist file and verified that those keys still exist and are the same as when the wallet was working
- Restarted numerous times
- Booted into recovery mode and disabled SIP again
- Tried all USB ports on my MAC
- Gone through pretty much every Ledger / Monero related issue on this forum

But still I haven't been able to get it working again. I was using a USB hub when I first installed it and I'm wondering if that was maybe the problem? Surely if it detects the device on one USB port then any port should work thereafter? At this stage I'm really grasping at straws as I have no idea how to get it working again and no longer have access to my funds - very frustrating.

I know a new version of the GUI is coming out mid-way through October to solve all these issues with Macs but would like to access my funds before then if possible!

Any help would be great (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a *different* USB cable (even though you verified that the current one *should* be working properly)?

Comment: Out of frustration I went and bought a new cable. lo and behold.. it worked! thanks man appreciate it! If you add this as the answer I'll mark it as solved (☞ﾟ∀ﾟ)☞

Comment: Don't forget to add that answer sir so I can mark it off. otherwise I'll add the answer just in case anyone else runs into the same frustrating issue

Comment: Ah, kind of forgot. I'll add one know.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predominant reason for a properly working Ledger & Monero setup to stop working is that the USB cable is either broken or slightly damaged (and therefore unable to function properly). Fortunately, this particular issue is easily resolved by buying a new USB cable. Alternatively, it could be that the USB port is not functioning properly anymore. You can easily check whether this is the culprit of your issue by using a different USB port.